Не работают Satic файлы на iPhone в Telegram Web App
Я создал сайт на fastapi. Он работает локально, но я пустил его через ngrok. Проблема такая: я открываю сайт через telegram web app и на пк и на андроиде все работает нормально, но на айфоне не работают скрипты и стили. Если открыть сайт просто через браузер, то все нормально работает стили и скрипт подключаются тоже нормально. Если прописать стили и скрипт в шаблоне, то тоже все работает нормально. Я проверил с двух айфонов и на обоих ни стили ни скрипт не работают. В консоли ошибок нет. А еще вместе со ссылкой на сайт я передаю telegram id пользователя.
